# Achievements bug on codegolf?

Tags: support

I'm not getting notified about my rep gain only on the code-golf site. But when I click the achievements box, I see a message displaying my rep gain.
Note:
This only occurs on code-golf and not on any other site. And it started yesterday only (everything was ok before).
How can I fix this.

Comment: have you tried reloading the page?

Comment: Yes I did. It doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any user scripts installed that might run only on codegolf.SE? That's the only "simple" explanation I can think of.

Comment: @Ilmari no I don't have anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I know what happened:

I lost 10 points due to a removed user, so I wasn't notified until my acheivements exeeded the 10 points.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's a threshold of 200 rep for this.

Edit: It appears I completely misunderstood the question. A user's top 3 or 4 accounts (with >200 rep on each) will appear in the left-most super-combo-box. But it seems this is not what the question was about.

Comment: It is working right now

Comment: @luser if that is so, why does the user have less than 200 rep, and never earned 200 rep in a day?

Comment: @user689 You should remove the check-mark since my answer is not correct.

Comment: @Quincunx My mistake. I've edited to explain what I thought I was talking about. :)